# Hide the 100% column when using the "Show value as % Of another base item" in Excel Pivot Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I'm doing some fairly light reporting in Excel and have run into a problem I can't seem to figure out on my own.

I have data in a format similar to this:

| ID | Location | QuestionText | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAL | Sick days | 3 |
| 2 | AAL | Work days | 6 |
| 3 | CPH | Sick days | 2 |
| 4 | CPH | Work days | 4 |

All I'm trying to achieve is a pivot chart, that has a single column per location, which shows the percentage of "Sick Days" compared to "Work Days".

I have done this by setting up the chart as:

- Location as "Axis"
- QuestionText as Legend (on the chart itself, I've filtered to only show for "Sick days"
- As my "Value" I have the Sum of the Value field with the following Value Field Settings:

  - "Summarize Values By": Sum
  - "Show Value As": % Of with "QuestionText" set as BaseField and "Sick Days" set as BaseItem
    [image]

It seems that adding the "Show as % Of" has the added effect of presenting not only the QuestionText I've filtered the chart to but also the value selected as the base item when.

I end up with a chart that looks like this
[image]

..where all the 100% columns are the base item selected previously. They are, by definition always at 100% and adds noise to the chart while also making the proportions of the "Sick Days" column less clear.

I've been looking for a way to get rid of the 100% column but without any success. Any tips or hints?

**Update per @cybernetic.nomad's suggestion**
When opening the "Select Data" window for the chart I have no option to remove the data set:
[image]

Comment: Right-click on the chart, choose "Select Data" and remove the 100% series

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad, thank you for your suggestion. The options are not available to me. All the buttons are greyed out. I've added a picture of what it looks like in the original post.